# Advanced Custom Fields — как вывести название поля?

Tags: wordpress

Advanced Custom Fields плагин.
Я понимаю как вывести значение поля в шаблоне, но не могу найти в мануалах как вывести перед этим еще и имя самого поля.

Т.е. нужно вот так вот сделать вывод.

Имя поля - его данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего случая - первый пример в коде. Я привел еще примеров, чтобы было понятно.

```
 <?php 

/*
*  Get a field object and display it with it's value
*/

$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];

/*
*  Get a field object and display it with it's value (using the field key and the value fron another post)
*/

$field_key = "field_5039a99716d1d";
$post_id = 123;
$field = get_field_object($field_key, $post_id);

echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];

/*
*  Get a field object and create a select form element
*/

$field_key = "field_5039a99716d1d";
$field = get_field_object($field_key);

if( $field )
{
    echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
        foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
}

?>
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

Comment: подскажите как при этом отедльно название поля можно в strong тег обернуть? не получилось

Comment: Так (с конкатенацией) echo '<strong>'. $field['label'] . ':</strong> ' . $field['value'];  - либо построчно, если так проще читать код:  echo '<strong>';
echo $field['label'];
echo ':</strong> ';
echo $field['value'];

Comment: Получилось. Подскажите еще как сделать чтобы это все не выводилось, если поле пусто? Стоит параметр необязательное, но выводится когда пустое.

Comment: Что-то вроде if ($field['value']) {
echo '<strong>'. $field['label'] . ':</strong> ' . $field['value']; 
 
 }

Comment: Спасибо, уже получилось вот так вот <?php if( get_field('equipment') ) : ?>
       // код который был
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Тут главное механизм понять :) Помню когда-то сам голову ломал над этими Custom Fields.